# capture photo inside app with original resolution in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm using camera intent to capture image inside my android app. After capturing I save pics into mobile internal/External storage in a specific folder. The problem is that these pics are not being saved in that resolution which camera has normally, their resolution is very low.

here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start ****************/
        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + File.separator + "ScannerMini";
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
         imageName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            myPath = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), imageName);
            //File myPath = new File(extr, imageName);
        }
        else{
         myPath = new File(extr, imageName);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext()
                    .getContentResolver(), bp, myPath.getPath(), imageName);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

can anybody tell me that what should i do to save image in original resolution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

By doing this you will only get a thumbnail image. You need to specify `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` option in your capture intent. This is a path where captured image will be stored. Refer to android docs [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)